# How to select all items from subcollections using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Could you please help me to select all int items from collection with subcollections.

I have object

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>>
```

and I need to select *all integers* in *one* `List<int>` or `int[]`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to *flatten* twice (with a help of `SelectMany`):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> source = ...

IEnumerable<int> result = source // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>>
  .SelectMany(outer => outer)    // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>
  .SelectMany(inner => inner);   // IEnumerable<int>
```

Finally, add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` in order to *materialize* `IEnumerable<int>` as `int[]` or `List<int>`:

```
int[] array = source 
  .SelectMany(outer => outer) 
  .SelectMany(inner => inner)
  .ToArray();
```